# Запуск цикла loop в методе

Tags: ruby

Собственно не могу понять, в чём причина моей проблемы, запускаю цикл `loop`, всё отрабатывает корректно, выводится некий список в терминале, но как только я его оборавичваю в метод, на этом всё заканчивается, при запуске ошибок нет, но и нет списка из цикла **loop**, подскажите куда копать?

Пример который работает:

```
loop do
  puts "Hello World"
  break
end
```

Пример того, что не работает, но нужно сделать:

```
 def menu
   loop do
   puts %Q(
   1. Посчитать цену молока
   )

   puts "Введите нужное число из меню:"

   input = gets.chomp

   case input
   when 1
     show_moloko
   end
 end
end

def show_moloko
  тут вычисляем
end
```

Comment: Не, ну так стало гораздо лучше, сразу понятно, в чем дело.

Comment: @Igor Довабил для наглядности пару примеров.

Comment: Вы функцию `menu` вызываете?

Comment: @Igor Я понимаю куда Вы клоните, нет я не вызываю, в цикле заключен ещё **case** с методами обработки по обращению к одному из пунктов меню, которое заключено в **puts**, каждый пункт меню цикла, это отдельный метод обработки.

Comment: Хм, так если `menu` нигде не вызывается, откуда возьмется вывод в терминале? Напишите `menu()` там, где раньше был `loop`.

Comment: @Igor loop это цикл и мне нужно его вызвать внутри метода

Comment: Это я понял. Но должен же кто-то вызвать метод, чтобы выполнились Ваши `loop` и `puts`.

Comment: @Igor я пробовал так вызывать, после метода объявлять метод для вызова, да цикл отрабатывает, но вот уже начинает ругаться на методы обработки, которые заключены в пунктах меню цикла и получаю такого рода ошибку: **undefined local variable or method**

Comment: Все. Вам пора показывать минимальный пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему. Потому что я не понимаю, что это значит - "после метода объявлять метод для вызова".

Comment: @Igor в первом методе записано меню в цикле и идет выбор, в заивисимости от выбора пункта меню из первого метода, выполняются методы обработки, которые прописаны в кейсе. Поправил пример.

Comment: Всё, разобрался, если в конце последнего метода вызвать метод в котором описан цикл, то цикл работает корректно, не знал. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ита-ак... вы со всем разобрались в итоге?

Comment: @D-side Будем считать что да, а так некоторые проблемы всё равно остались.